# Difference between .dae and .stl files

Tags: ros, dae

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Can anyone explain me where is the difference in between .dae files and .stl files?

I am not sure but i always thought .stl files are used in ROS and .dae files in Gazebo, but im not sure!

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215997/difference-between-.dae-and-.stl-files/) by [DonnY](https://answers.ros.org/users/21798/donny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-08-18**:
Duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/39959/stl-vs-dae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See Wikipedia on [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) and [COLLADA/DAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA). Essentially, stl is the simpler variant of representing a mesh and only allows for surface geometry information. In contrast, dae files use XML and allow to embed much richer information, such as color, texture and other data. Both are supported by various ROS tools (rviz, moveit etc.) and Gazebo.

I'd recommend using stl if you don't need the additional capabilities dae offers, as it's simpler (and smaller in binary format).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6